# Selecting and Copying Text without Editing Description Field

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

In the SharePoint Online experience, I have developed a few lists that track Change Request and Support tickets. Site users have noted that you cannot right click and select all for a field, or highlight the text without first going into edit mode for the "Multiple Lines Of Text" field.

Has anyone performed a work-around on this issue? Didn't want to go into the SP Designer and start playing with things.

Comment: after right click on the contents of multiline field, did you find any option like "Copy field to clipboard"? I am using this option in Teams site to copy multiline field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the modern experience, the detail information panel (right panel) for displaying properties of an item does not allow users to select any content in that. Thus, you cannot select and copy any thing in detail information panel. Users can only copy content in edit mode.

To work around this, you can switch to classic experience by clicking “Return to classic SharePoint” in the bottom, left corner of the page to switch to classic experiences. Users can copy field values including multiple-lines of text field values in classic experience.

By the way, you can submit your feedback to [SharePoint UserVoice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/) for this requirement as the modern experience is a new feature and is in the improving phase. If a feedback is high voted there by other customers, it would be promising that Microsoft Product Team will take it into consideration when designing the next version in the future.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, it's too bad this is the only method, because the classic experience just removes everything they have upgraded in the view and it looks blocky and unstructured.
It would seem that just "dealing with it" is the favored option until as you said they update the platform.